# Visual difference between html list item and paragraph

Tags: html, css

For a html `<li>` element, the textual content begins after some spacing on the left. I don't know how to say it properly. But I am referring to the space I drew with the red line as shown in the picture below:

[image]

For a `<p>` element there is no such spacing in the textual content. Picture below:

[image]

I am unfamiliar if there is some CSS term that is used to describe this effect ?

I am also curious if it is possible for content inside the  `<p>` element to have that kind of spacing as seen in the `<li>` element ?

Thank you.

Comment: At some point you have to wonder why you'd want to use a paragraph to mimic a numbered list tho.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the li inside ul tag is just we write a list of items in paper. We don't give the number to li tag, it does automatically(you can also disable this with CSS)

the p tag is used to write a paragraph, just like we write in the paper. In this, the number is put by you

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the answer to your question is no. However, there is a CSS paragraph attribute called text-indent, which is used to indent the first like of a paragraph by whatever you set it to. You can use this same attribute and give it a negative amount, thereby taking the first line and shifting it to before the paragraph start position. You will then also need to play around with left margin to match the negative indent:

```css
p {
  text-indent: -1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp), they have kind of different default css styles. li is displayed as list-item, whether p is displayed as block. Paragraph has margin as well.

Answer (score 0):

The property that controls the indent in your `<ol>` example is it's left padding.

You *can* simulate the look of a list with `<p>` elements a number of different ways. In my example, I'm giving them a common parent which acts as the `<ol>` (or `<ul>`) and controls the indentation. The ordinal numbers can be [CSS pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) — I'm using `::before` because it puts the pseudo-element in a convenient position — with a sufficient negative margin to "pull" them into the [parent's] left-padding. You can auto-generate the numerals using [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

```css
ol {
  width: 200px;
}

body {
  counter-reset: ordinal;
}

.list-like {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 0 0 2.5em;
}

.list-like>p::before {
  counter-increment: ordinal;
  content: counter( ordinal)'.';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2.25em;
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Ordered List</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo delectus accusantium soluta illo ea animi repellat officia esse, quisquam illum!</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ol>

<h1>Simulated Ordered List</h1>
<div class="list-like">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse ratione, repellat voluptates nisi tempore soluta obcaecati! Nihil culpa earum praesentium!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```